# Apache Camel: Send half of data to one route and other half to second route. Camel Load balancer not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a use case of sending messages reading from file and send half of the total records to one kafka producer and other half to second kafka producer.

I tried with load balancing option. It does send to only one producer(the first one).

```
from(itemFileConfig.getWorkingDir())
                .log("Entered into file consumption part::")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .process(fileProcessor)
                .loadBalance()
                .roundRobin()
                .to("direct:kafkaPosting1")
                .to("direct:kafkaPosting2")
                .end();


from("direct:kafkaPosting1")
                .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
                .to("kafka:" + config.getTopicName() + "?" + "brokers=" +
                        config.getBoostStapServers1() + "&" +"serializerClass=" +
                        config.getSerializer())
                .end();



from("direct:kafkaPosting2")
                    .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
                    .to("kafka:" + config.getTopicName() + "?" + "brokers=" +
                            config.getBoostStapServers2() + "&" +"serializerClass=" +
                            config.getSerializer())
                    .end();
```

Any help or idea would be very much appreciated.
I see content based routing using choice but I need a predicate of something like even-odd to separate it out.. Didn't find any help online on the same..

Thanks in advance

Comment: As indicated [in the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/eips/loadBalance-eip.html) the load balancer acts on a per-message premise though you seem to only have one message which you send to the respective endpoint and then perform the split. Try splitting before using the load balancer and see whether that fixes your issue

Comment: Thanks a lot Roman.. your suggestion worked..

Comment: You should be able to define a 50/50 split like this: `.loadBalance().weighted(true, "1:1")`, though this should equal the default behavior